# Unique factorization of integers vs. unique factorization of graphs

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory

As you know, graphs can be factorized in their component subgraphs, factors such as eventually semilattices, and so on. I would like to know about the precise nature of the relation that might hold (if any) between such graph decomposition(s) and the (unique) factorization of an integer number in its prime constituents. Is there any known theorem regulating such an alleged relation?

Thanks in advance (examples are welcome).